# securely passing a password to subprocess.Popen via environment

Tags: python, security, passwords, subprocess

I would like to securely ask a password to a user and then pass it to subprocess.Popen to run a command that requires it.

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52989658/python-subprocess-popen-pass-passwords-securely) and that [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387731/use-subprocess-to-send-a-password), but I wonder if I can securely pass the password via the subprocess environment like that:

```
import subprocess, os
user_password = input("what is you password?")
my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env["userpass"] = user_password
my_command = "python --version"
subprocess.Popen(my_command, env=my_env)
```

Will the password be flushed once the python script is closed ? I have look at the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html) but it's not explained.

When I add this line `print(os.environ['userpass'])` at the end of my code to print the OS environment, I can retrieve the user password. Do it means that the password can be access by the other running processes ?

Edit: I can't pipe the password as the command I use doesn't read its password from standard input

Comment: I'd pipe it into the subprocess.  Trying to hide it in the environment is maybe marginally better than on the cmdline, but it's still accessible `/proc/<pid>/environ` (in linux at least).

Comment: It looks like the environment trick is just as risky on Windows too, btw ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255968/view-environment-variable-of-process-on-windows))

Comment: Thanks for your help! Regarding cmdline. When you say cmdline, you mean this: I run the command directly in Windows command prompt, wait for the command to ask the password and then I type it? Is this unsafe?

Comment: regarding pipe: do you mean doing something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41094357/3154274

Comment: (a) no that's safe, I mean when you first type the name of your program to call it -- *that's* the line I was referring to, not anything you enter subsequently.  (b) Yes, that's what I mean re: piping it.

Comment: @jedwards, thanks for suggesting the stdin way but the command I use doesn't read its password from standard input

Comment: @jedwards Still, the environment also in ´/proc/<pid>/environ/` is only readable by the current user and `root` so it is not accessible to other users, at least. But I agree that it is less safe, and better alternatives are normally available.

Comment: What ways can passwords be entered into the command you use? Apparently it can read environment variables but not over `stdin`? Are there other ways, e.g. from a `pty´? In that case, have a look at `pexpect´? (Or potentially roll your own input function using `pty` directly.)

Comment: @JohanL, sorry for the delay, I need to send the password to rclone and I think the only way is by setting the environment cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588368